Error to find references in Visual Studio 2019
I noticed that every time I open a cloned project in a new environment (with Visual Studio 2019), the project cannot find the references it uses.
I know that I can add the references again to solve the errors, but the strange thing is that when I click on the error listing lines, the reference in that specific file is resolved. However, other lines of errors that use the SAME reference are not resolved.
So, I need to double-click all lines and wait for the error to disappear.
The sequence of acts that I do (after clone and open the project in VS2019) is:
1 - Try to build
2 - Errors appear
3 - I click on each line
4 - The error for that line is resolved
And this goes in a loop until all are resolved.
I tried to rebuild project.
If I remove all references and add again, it works, but the problem is that I shouldn't have to be doing this.
